# How do I run Groovy scripts as Java, from the command line?

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying to use groovyc, but something is not right:

```
>echo println("Hello world") > test.groovy
>groovy test.groovy
Hello world
>groovyc test.groovy
>java -cp C:\utils\groovy-1.8.1\embeddable\groovy-all-1.8.1.jar test
Error: Could not find or load main class test

>dir test.class
...

11/10/2011  02:54 PM             7,104 test.class
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you specify the classpath with `-cp` switch, its default value (current directory) is overwritten and so JVM can't find your class.

Add current directory to classpath, and everything works:

```
>java -cp C:\utils\groovy-1.8.1\embeddable\groovy-all-1.8.1.jar;. test
Hello, world
```

Comment: I tried that before ... back when I was adding `c:\utils\groovy-1.8-1\lib` to the class path. Haven't tried it after switching to groovy-all, works like a charm.

Comment: In Linux, it would be something like: `java -cp "/path_to/groovy-all-x.x.x.jar:." test`

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that if you are using a unix based system (Linux or Mac), then you need colon instead of semicolon for classpath entry separator:

```
>java -cp /path/to/groovy/embeddable/groovy-all-1.8.1.jar:. test
Hello, world
```

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure these snippets will work, since class with main method is missed.
Proper command line is:

```
java -cp /path/to/groovy/embeddable/groovy-all-1.8.1.jar groovy.lang.GroovyShell test.groovy
```